# Dispatcher.CheckAccess returning true from an unmanaged worker thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, unmanaged

I have code as follows:

```
   public override void Touch()
   {
        if ( System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.CheckAccess() )
        {
            TouchBase();
        }
        else
        {
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Send,
                    (Action) (() => TouchBase()) );
        }
    }
```

And I have just got a crash in the if block (not the else block) because certain things in there must be done on the main thread, and the call stack clearly indicates this is not the main thread, but an unmanaged IOCP thread.

So my question is, does CheckAccess() not work when called from an unmanaged thread or something?  Can it really be that broken?  Anyone got any ideas what's happening here.  By the way, this problem occurs very rarely, so a suggestion to add some logging isn't really that useful.

Comment: This is a bit wierd? Can you also try with Dispatcher. VerifyAccess(). This will throw an exception if there is no access and does not return a bool. [Verify Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.verifyaccess.aspx)

Comment: not easily, it took about an hour to crash.  In fact, no I can't, if you look at the code, sometimes it will be called by the main thread, others not.  It needs to keep working in both cases, I don't want to pollute that code with try{}catch blocks and stuff.

Comment: very true.sorry cant be of any help. I am quite interested about this issue and the fix.

Answer (score 0):

It seems (it will take me a while to be certain of this) that the correct thing to do is call System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess() instead.  System.Windows.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher() creates a new dispatcher if it is not set, which it seems is the case when the thread is unmanaged.

Comment: The MS doco could be a lot more clear on this, specifically mentioning what it means when callbacks from unmanaged threads are involved.

Answer (score 0):

System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher gives you the the Dispatcher for the *currently executing* thread, not the thread on which the dispatcher for the application.  Every thread has a dispatcher -- but this is not the dispatcher you are looking for.

System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher is the main dispatcher for the application.  If you use that in both places you should be fine.